# Cannot build iOS ad-hoc in Codename One

Tags: ios, codenameone

While testing how Codename One iOS build works I found no way to make an ad-hoc build. I gave my Apple Developer credentials in CN1 to be used in the build process and CN1 correctly gave me the option to select the unique devices I had set up at the Apple Developer end. I got no errors and everything seemed to be ok.

However, after that process the only options I had for an iOS build were "debug build" and "Appstore build", the latter being grayed out. If I decide to move to CN1 I really need the ad-hoc option because the apps are definitely not going to the app store but installed through enterprise delivery channel(s).

So how can one do an ad-hoc release build? Or is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

In Codename One Settings under the "iOS Signing" section you should see these options:

[image: iOS Signing Options]

Comment: Well, running the wizard cleared what I had done at the Apple end (I understand I should not have advised the wizard to revoke them because it invalidated the Ionic apps some people were still using). Well, I got new certificates from the wizard and used them. However, the build stops now with a message "A certificate from Apple with the appropriate password is required for building an iOS native app!"  This being everything I get I have no idea how to continue.

Comment: Finally found out what the problem was. There was a space in the directory name "Codename One".  Having used spaces in file and directory names since Windows NT I could not expect this to become a problem. Sigh.

Comment: It should work, there is a regression in Windows only related to this. I think there is an issue in the issue tracker. Notice that invalidating a certificate doesn't impact applications deployed to itunes only debug applications installed on development devices...

Comment: That was an iMac I have very reluctantly been using for these projects so it has problems with MacOS as well (or probably MacOS only).

Comment: Odd. I'll try to reproduce this on my Mac. Thanks!

Comment: When changing "Codename one" to "Codenameone"I remember editing away a URL-encoded %20 from where a space should have been so something must have done that and I cannot believe it was the MacOS! A roundtrip to the server? Java code in the configuration utility doing that? It definitely was not me, at least :)

Comment: The new plugin release tries to workaround it by checking for a space in the new project wizard. It's not ideal but when we started digging through the code we were concerned we might make a fix in one place only to run into the problem in a different place.